# Making a container scrollable

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this view in my app

[image]

and this is the code for it:

```
return Container(
  color: Colors.black,
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ...
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

But if I click on my form I get stuck and the list of items is hidden by the keyboard, so I'd like to make my Container scrollable.

[image]

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping your `Column` with a `ListView` try with a `SingleChildScrollView` instead. You can also try adding a bottom padding equal to keyboard size `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom`.

Comment: Using SingleChildScrollView didn't solve my problem, tomorrow I'll try adding a bottom padding